# No crontab for user, yet cron jobs are running

Tags: cron

I have no apparent crontab:

```
$ contab -l
no crontab for gauthier
```

Yet, something seems to be running as my user:

```
$ tail /var/log/syslog
...
Apr 13 16:25:01 sobel CRON[22043]: (gauthier) CMD (rsync -av --delete /home/gauthier/.encrypted/ /home/gauthier/Google\ Drive/encrypted)
...
```

I recognize the command, it's something I've had a while ago.

Why is the crontab running, as my user, although it's not in the result of `crontab -l`? `sudo crontab -l` is also empty.

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/gauthier`?

Comment: `grep -R rsync /etc/cron*` (system-wide `crontab` etc. perhaps).

Comment: They could be in `/etc/crontab`, in which we also specify the user tobe run as.

Comment: @zhongfu: right, I should have mentioned that. There is no such file (the directory exists).

Comment: @moon.musick, @muru: Thanks for the hints. No luck though. I keep a log of what I do when I set up this kind of things (yes, I do, can you believe it? And I have traces of what I did there). Apparently, I did set the job with `crontab -e`. What could possibly have happened is that I fiddled with UID afterwards. `sudo ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs` is empty, or so it seems.